# Dynamic linking and encounter dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found:

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking, libtool

I am in `autotool` environment.

I am developing a library `A` which uses library `B` and `C` as dependencies.

- I build `B` with `libtool` so the output is `libB.la`
- I build `C` with simple Makefile and the output is `libC.a`
- I build `A` with libtool as well and the output is `libA.la`

Then I build a test program which linked these libraries together.

The `Makefile.am` is below.

```
check_PROGRAMS = acc_test

AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/include \
              -I$(top_srcdir)/deps/C/include \
              -I$(top_srcdir)/deps/B/include


LDADD = $(top_builddir)/src/libA.la \
        $(top_builddir)/deps/B/src/libB.la \
        $(top_builddir)/deps/C/libC.a

acc_test_SOURCES = test.cpp
```

When I run `acc_test`, I encounter

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN7leveldb7OptionsC1Ev
>     Referenced from: /Users/somepath/build/src/.libs/libA.0.dylib
>     Expected in: flat namespace
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN7leveldb7OptionsC1Ev
>     Referenced from: /Users/somepath/cw/build/src/.libs/libA.0.dylib
>     Expected in: flat namespace

This is my main problem.

After I have tried many things, I found that.

- It crashed when invoking some functions of `C` library inside `A`. If I comment them out of `A` code, it doesn't crash.
- Case 1: If I write code using `C` explicitly in the `test.cpp`, it doesn't crash.
- Case 2: If I add `AM_LDFLAGS = -static`, it doesn't crash.
- Case 3: I tried to simulate the same situation with `B`, it doesn't crash.

My questions are below

1. Why does it crash in the first place? I guess it is about dynamic loading but I don't understand it thoroughly.
2. In case 1, why does it not crash?
3. In case 2, why does it not crash?
4. Are there any other ways to solve this problem without `-static`? I think it's weird if the user needed to linked these libraries statically when they want to use my library `A`
5. In case 3, why does it not crash? I notice that many implementation of lib `B` are in the headers. Does it involve?

Thank you